# R parallel package - performance very slow in my toy example

Tags: r, parallel-processing, package

I am trying to sample for two vectors 1000 times with replacement and calculate the ratio of means. Repeat this process 10,000 times.

I wrote a sample parallel code but it's taking much longer that using simple for loops on a single machine.

```
ratio_sim_par <- function(x1, x2, nrep = 1000) {

# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) #Leave one core for other operations 

clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("x1", "x2", "nrep"), envir=environment())

Tboot <- parLapply(cl, 1:nrep, function(x){

    n1 <- length(x1)
    n2 <- length(x2) 

    xx1 <- sample(x1, n1, replace = TRUE) # sample of size n1 with replacement from x1
    xx2 <- sample(x2, n2, replace = TRUE) # sample of size n2 with replacement from x2
    return(mean(xx1) / mean(xx2))  
})

stopCluster(cl)

return(unlist(Tboot))

}

ratio_sim_par(x1, x2, 10000)
```

System time is unbearable. Can anyone help me understand the mistake I'm making? Thanks

Comment: Going parallel doesn't necessarily add efficiency (at least not linearly: https://support.nesi.org.nz/hc/en-gb/articles/360001173895-OpenMP-Scaling-Example). The more you parallelise the larger the overhead since `parallel` will be basically creating a new instance of R per core assigned. How many cores are you using? Have you tried some tests on subsets in serial and parallel using different numbers of cores?

Comment: Yes, this is for small proof of concept. I kind of get the overhead in parallel but still like to organize the above code or similar logic that is more efficient on multicore. Currently, we have 8 cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributing tasks to different nodes takes a lot of computational overhead and can cancel out any gains you make from parallelizing your script. In your case, you're calling `parLapply` 10,000 times and probably spending more resources forking each task than actually doing the resampling. Try something like this with a non-parallel version of `ratio_sim_par`:

```
mclapply(1:10000, ratio_sim_par, x1, x2, nrep = 1000, mc.cores = n_cores)
```

`mclapply` will split the job into as many cores as you have available and fork it once. I'm using `mclapply` instead of `parLapply` because I'm used to it and doesn't require as much setup.

Comment: A few comments: `mclapply()` relies on _forked_ processing.  Forked processing is not supported in R by all OSes - Windows is _not_ supported.  Some functions are _not_ fork safe, e.g. they might crash your R session - sometimes this happens at random and is often hard to troubleshoot. Because of this, I would never use `mclapply()` on production code that I'm not in full control over "all the way down". It is advised against using forked processing RStudio Console.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikB, I didn't realize there was a major difference between `mclapply` and `parLapply`. This might help me with a separate project I've been developing to run on a cluster